# Lightning Record edit from to make the Fields Read only based on the picklist value selected

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I am trying to create a Lightning component  to make the Fields as read only based on the picklist value selected I have custom Field(status) when ever user selects the value in the picklist as (New,upgraded,old,current) the fields  should not be editable by user  only user can view the Data in the Fields. I have tried creating record View Form but unable to figure it out on how can we achieve it based on the condition . Can someone please help or provide an example

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Detail Information">
        <lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name="NHPMS__Patient__c"
        record-id={recordId}>   
                <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages> 
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field
                           field-name="NHPMS__First_Name__c"
                       ></lightning-input-field>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field
                           field-name=" NHPMS__Last_Name__c"
                       ></lightning-input-field>
                   </div> 
                   <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                    <lightning-input-field
                           field-name="NHPMS__Medical_Record__c"
                       ></lightning-input-field>
                   </div> 
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">                          
                <lightning-input-field
                field-name="status__c"
                onchange={handleStatusChange} >           
</lightning-input-field>
</div>  
</div>
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
     <lightning-input-field
            field-name="Department__c"
            read-only={isReadOnly}
        ></lightning-input-field>
    </div>  
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
             <lightning-input-field
            field-name="Discharge_Date__c"
            read-only={isReadOnly}
            ></lightning-input-field>
        </div>  
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
             <lightning-input-field
                field-name="Date_of_Birth__c"
                read-only={isReadOnly}
            ></lightning-input-field>
        </div>
    </div>
           <lightning-button class="slds-var-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Save">
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button class="slds-var-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Cancel">
        </lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import {LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class RecordLwcForm extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    isReadOnly = false;  
  handleStatusChange(event){
      if(event.detail.value === 'old'){
          this.isReadOnly = true;
      } 
      if(event.detail.value === 'new'){
        this.isReadOnly = true;
    } 
    if(event.detail.value === 'upgraded'){
        this.isReadOnly = true;
    } 
      else {
          this.isReadOnly = false;
      }
  }
  
  }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
     <targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>  
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image: Record Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use the `lightning-record-edit-form` instead of `lightning-record-view-form` since you also need the ability to conditionally edit the records. Then, you can use `lightning-input-field` and set the `read-only`    attribute to true or false based on your conditions.

Here is how the code would look like

```
<lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        record-id={recordId}
>
                
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={accountField}
            read-only={isReadOnly}
        ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={nameField}
            read-only={isReadOnly}
        ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field
            field-name={statusField}
            onchange={handleStatusChange}
        ></lightning-input-field>
...
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

```
...
isReadOnly = false;

handleStatusChange(event){
    if(event.detail.value === 'ABC'){
        this.isReadOnly = true;
    } else {
        this.isReadOnly = false;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Hi @Aditya  I have custom picklist Field called(Current_status) when user selects the Picklist value as  (New,upgraded,old,current) any of the  values i need to make other Fields as Read only currently  all the Fields are editable and The Current status Field is in a different section and other Fields are in Different section in the record Page. Can you provide an example or code on how can be  it achieved using any of the values selected as picklist value to make the Fields Read only

Comment: I updated the answer with code snippets. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Aditya Thanks a Quick question  so when ever user change the status to NEW the below condition  will make the Field as Readonly    right                                              isReadOnly = false;

handleStatusChange(event){
    if(event.detail.value === 'NEW'){
        this.isReadOnly = true;
    } else {
        this.isReadOnly = false;
    }
}

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Hi Aditya, I have edited my post with the code i have deployed the code in my org but  after deploying  i have added it to the record page but i can't see any fields visible under the section . Currently My page Layout has three sections the  Header section has the status Field the Role section Fields  should be  Read only Do i need to create SLDS GRID layout and could you help me why i can't see the Fields after deploying .

Comment: The object-api-name and field-name attribute have to either be strings, or field references. For example: `object-api-name="NHPMS__Patient__c"` or `field-name="Discharge_Date__c"`. If you have put a binding, it should be to a field reference.. For example: if `field-name={dischargeDate}`, then in your JS file, you need to have `import DISCHARGE_DATE from '@salesforce/...../fieldName'`, and then inside the class you need to assign the imported field to a property like `dischargeDate = DISCHARGE_DATE`

Comment: See https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordEditFormDynamicContact and https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordEditFormStaticContact for reference

Comment: Thanks Aditya it worked now i have changed the object api name and field name to strings but my Status Field is in the Header section do i need to create a  Grid section and all the Fields  using lightning input Field and add a slds Grid and Create a Role sections

Comment: Yes, the UI is in your control.

Comment: Hi Aditya I have given the  multiple picklist values condition and when i select the status as upgraded i am able to edit  the department, discharged,DOB field . Could you please help me if there is wrong with the  above code

Comment: You'll have to combine the if conditions... `if(a===b || b===c || ...) { readonly = true } else{ readonly= false }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128381/discussion-between-vijay-and-aditya-naag).

Answer (score 1):

As per lwc [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form/documentation)

> Use the lightning-record-view-form component to create a form that displays Salesforce record data for specified fields associated with that record. The fields are rendered with their labels and current values as **read-only**.

For this you need to use [`record-form`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/specification) where you can dynamically set the `layout-type` property based on the custom field value.

Comment: Hi @Damecek  Thanks i am trying to figure out how can i make the Fields Readonly based on the Picklist selected value of the current status Field i have 4 picklist values when user selects any of the values user should  not be able to edit the Field of other Field values can you provide an example of the Picklist values or code snippet on exactly how can we achieve the above